# How to read populated columns only with CFSpreadsheet

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I am trying to use `<cfspreadsheet>` to read data from a spreadsheet and insert that data into a database table. Let's say my table has 10 possible columns: `FName,LName,MName, Address1,Address2,Address3,city,state,zip and email`. Users will be able to submit data using Excel, but they don't have to submit data for all 10 columns. They could just submit data for `FName,Email` or `FName, LName, City, Email`. My spreadsheet code should be able to read only the columns submitted in their Excel file, instead of reading all the blank columns.

I thought by using the "columnnames" attribute of `<cfspreadsheet>` I can instruct cfspreadsheet to just read data from those column names, unfortunately I was wrong OR I did it wrong?

[image: Results of CFSpreadsheet Code]

Here is my cfspreadsheet code:

```
 <cfspreadsheet action="read" 
     src="#Trim(PathToExcelFile)#" 
     columnnames="#Trim(Form.UserColumnList)#" 
     excludeheaderrow="true" 
     query="FindData">
 </cfspreadsheet>
```

[image: Mapping List and resulting Query]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is stored in form.userColumnList?  Do a <cfoutput>/<cfdump> on it right before the call to <cfspreadsheet> please.

Comment: Hi Scott, the user.ColumnList is a list of available columns in user's excel file. The cfdump show: LName,FName,MName,HomeAddr1. Different user may submit an excel with a different columns, such as, LName,FName,MName,HomeAddr1, HomeAddr2,HomeAddr3,HomeCity.HomeState,HomeZip

Comment: (Edit) "columnNames" does not determine what columns cfspreadsheet reads.  It renames the query columns in "FindData", to something more meaningful than "col_1,col_2, etcetera...". Perhaps you are thinking of the `columns` attribute?

Comment: After searching for either columns and columnnames attributes I still don't quite understand what they do to the query FindData.

Comment: Why not read the spreadsheet to a variable instead of a query and read the first row to see what's been submitted?

Comment: @user3779216 - How many columns does the submitted file actually contain? In other words, does it only contain two (2) columns - "LName,FirstName" OR does it contain all ten (10) columns, but only some of them are populated with data? Regarding your question, the `columns` attribute tells cfspreadsheet to only read the data from certain columns. `columnNames` does not change what it reads. It simply tells cfspreadsheet what names you want to use for the query columns.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you elaborate what do you mean by " 
Why not read the spreadsheet to a variable instead of a query .."?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it correctly. After my codes read the spreadsheet using cfspreadsheet & if the spreadsheet does not have column names, then the query will look like the screenshot I attached to this question. My table on the other hand, has column names, such as, FName, LName, etc. How should I write my codes so that it can insert the data from Col_1 into FName in my table & Col_2 values go to LName column on my table? instead of Col_1 into Address,Col_2 ito City ? I know I have to using something like mapping but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

> **user3779216 wrote:** ... apparently each institution (there are 9 of them) will have a different excel layout. I may be able to create a UI for the users to map col names from their excel to col names from my table, such as, a drop down of column names from excel and a drop down of column names from my table and let user select which col from excel match which col from my table.

Actually that would make it dead simple. Just feed an *ordered* list of columns into cfspreadsheet, the way you were originally doing, and the query column names will automatically be mapped correctly.

For example, if the user uploaded the layout below: 
[image: Uploaded File Layout]

.. and selected this column order:

- Zip,Address1,LName,FName,Email,MName,Address2,City,State

Feeding that list into cfspreadsheet produces a query with desired column mappings, which you can use as normal. (If needed, add code to detect and skip optional header names in the first row.)

[image: CFSpreadsheet query results]

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" 
     src="#variables.pathToFile#"
     columnNames="#form.OrderedColumnNames#"
     query="sheetData" />

<cfdump var="#variables.sheetData#">
```

**NB:** Obviously the real code should include validation of the input list. Ensure it contains all of the required columns and was not tampered with to include invalid characters, etcetera.

Comment: Oh is that what the columnNames attribute is for?? let me work on it and see. Thank you Leigh!

Comment: Leigh, I almost got it. One problem is, I have to make this app as flexible as possible. Assuming my table has 20 columns but users are allowed to upload their excel with only 6 columns, ex:FN (col_1) and LN (col_2), MN(col_3),addr1(col_4), addr2 (col_5), addr3 (col_6). After my mapping, I got a column Name List like this: FN,LN,MN,Addr1,Addr2 ,Addr3. When I use this in the columnNames Attribute, only FN,LN and MN header is positioned in the right place but not address 1,2,3. Is there a way to show you what I did? this comment box limit me from doing that.

Comment: (Edit) As long as the data columns are contiguous and start in spreadsheet column A, it should work correctly.  To be sure I am understanding correctly, can you edit your question to include 1) a screenshot of the actual spreadsheet (just first row) AND 2) the resulting query object after you you apply the mappings above?

Comment: Leigh, I can only add 1 image at a time? I replaced my first image with the excel. I can't dd more images

Comment: I added 1 more image. It's the image but I'm not allowed to add more than two images.

Comment: Actually looking closer, do the empty columns J,K,L an M represent valid data columns they chose not to populate (ie table allows 14 possible columns, but the user only populated 6 of them)? If yes, they should be specifying the order of *all* of the possible columns in the UI form (whether they are populated or not). That is what the code above is designed to do . If you do that, the code should work as expected.

Comment: *they should be specifying the order of all of the possible columns in the UI form* IMO that is what a user would expect when uploading a file with empty (ie placeholder) columns.

Comment: What did you end up doing?